# Proof of supremum

Tags: real-analysis

Let E be a nonempty bounded subset of R. Let λ ∈ R and define
λE = {λx : x ∈ E}.
Prove that
sup(λE) = max{λ sup E, λ inf E}.

Hint: Substantial partial credit will be given if you prove that if λ ≥ 0, then sup(λE) = λ sup E.

Answer: I have gotten so far as to say that we know that the Sup(λE) exists since this is a nonempty bounded subset. I tried by starting to prove the hint, but I got stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use an $\epsilon$-argument.

I will show one side of the equality for $\lambda > 0$. It suffices to show that for each given $\epsilon >0$
$$\lambda \sup( E) \leq \sup(\lambda E) +\epsilon.$$
From the definition of $\sup$, there exists $x\in E$ such that 
$$\sup (E) -x \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}$$
$$\lambda \sup (E) - \lambda x \leq \epsilon$$
therefore
$$\lambda \sup (E) \leq \lambda x + \epsilon \leq \sup (\lambda E) + \epsilon.$$

Comment: could you quick explain how you got the inequality sup(E)−x≤ϵ/λ

Comment: The existence of $x$ is from the definition of supremum. As soon as I move below the supremum, then there exists a element $x\in E$ such that $$x \geq \sup(E) - \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}.$$